# If for an open cover there exists a partition of unity subordinated to it, then the cover has an open locally finite refinement.

Tags: paracompactness

In the Engelkings book "General Topology" in the chapter of paracompactness there is a lemma related to partitions of unity and locally finite covers.

I am trying to understand the proof of the lemma, but I am blocked at the part when $V_s$ sets are defined. I can't get why $V_s$ are open, why $\mathcal{V}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{U}$ and why $\mathcal{V}$ is locally finite.

The lemma together with the proof is given below:[image].

Comment: What is Engelking's notion of "a partition of unity subordinated to an open cover"? If it is the same as I would call thus, the proof is needlessly complicated, $W_s = \{x \in X : f_s(x) > 0\}$ would give a locally finite refinement without much ado.

Comment: A partition of unity $\{ f_s(x) \}_{s\in S}$ is subordinated to an open cover $\mathcal{A}$ if the cover $\{ f^{-1}_s((0,1]) \}_{s\in S}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{A}.$

Comment: And does "partition of unity" imply that the supports are a locally finite family for Engelking?

Comment: In this literature the notion of support is not used!

Comment: I see. That's why the simpler construction above doesn't work in Engelking's setting, he uses a wider definition of partition of unity.

Comment: Okay, so if we write $V_s = \{x \in X : f_s(x) - \frac{1}{2}f(x) > 0\}$, can you see why that is an open set?

Comment: I still didn't get it, until the above answer was posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $s\in S$ let $h_s(x)=f_s(x)-\frac12f(x)$; $h_s$ is continuous (because $f_s$ and $f$ are), so

$$V_s=\{x\in X:h_s(x)>0\}=h_s^{-1}\big[(0,\to)\big]$$

is open. For each $x\in V_s$ we have $\color{red}{f_s(x)>\frac12f(x)}>0$ by the definition of $f$, so $x\in f_s^{-1}\big[(0,1]\big]$. The partition of unity is subordinated to $\mathscr{U}$, so by definition there is a $U\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $V_s\subseteq f_s^{-1}\big[(0,1]\big]\subseteq U$, and $\mathscr{V}$ is a refinement of $\mathscr{U}$.

Finally, let $g=\frac12f$, and let $x\in X$; $f(x)>0$, so $g(x)>0$, and therefore there are a nbhd $U_0$ of $x$ and a finite $S_0\subseteq S$ such that $f_s(y)<g(y)=\frac12f(y)$ for all $y\in U_0$ and $s\in S\setminus S_0$. Let $s\in S\setminus S_0$ and $y\in U_0$; then $f_s(y)<\frac12f(y)$, so $y\notin V_s$ (by the red inequality above). Thus, $U_0\cap V_s=\varnothing$ for all $s\in S\setminus S_0$, so $\{s\in S:U_0\cap V_s\ne\varnothing\}\subseteq S_0$, and $U_0$ is therefore a nbhd of $x$ that meets only finitely many members of $\mathscr{V}$. Since $x\in X$ was arbitrary, this shows that $\mathscr{V}$ is locally finite.

Comment: This lemma is due to C. H. Dowker? Any references?

Comment: @MehmetOnat: I don’t know about the lemma, but Engelking says that this proof of it is due to M.R. Mather in a 1964 preprint *Paracompactness and partitions of unity*.

Comment: On page 213. https://www.google.com.tr/books/edition/Introduction_to_Topology/UQiZDwAAQBAJ?hl=tr&gbpv=1&dq=We+remark+that+the+converse+of+the+preceding+theorem+(due+to+C.+H.+Dowker&pg=PA213&printsec=frontcover. But no references

Comment: Actually, I want to prove that if for an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of a space $X$ there exists a partition of unity $\left\{ f_{i}\right\} _{i\in I}$ subordinated to it then  $X$ is a paracompact space.

Comment: Michael's article  note on paracompact spaces, (Proposition 2) In short, he proves it.

Comment: Is the book of M. R. Mather available online?

Comment: @MehmetOnat: I don’t know whether the Mather paper was even published: Engelking mentions only a preprint of it.

Comment: It is referred to as Mather, Paracompactness and partitions of unity, Mimeographed Notes 1964; PhD thesis,. Cambridge University, 1965 in literature.

Comment: @MehmetOnat: So the mimeographed notes must be the preprint that Engelking mentions and must contain material that went into Mather’s PhD thesis. So far as I can discover, that was never published and does not appear anywhere online.